# Is there a lib for WCF (REST) and the .NET SOAP stack to export req/resp to HAR format?

Tags: .net, wcf

We are trying to make our code easier to troubleshoot, so we want it to save to a log file that we can then import into fiddler, etc. We call REST services from WCF, and SOAP calls from the .NET SOAP lib.

The HAR format: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/

Seems to fit the bill!

Is there a .NET lib out there to make it easy to log my req/resp to HAR ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For SOAP I've always logged the raw Xml to a file or db from an instance of IDispatchMessageInspector.

After that it's trivial to run the message from SoapUi.

Here's a good blog on writing such a thing:

https://github.com/geersch/WcfMessageLogging